# Wie drückt man aus, dass man sich falsch in dieser Welt fühlt?

Tags: word-choice

Viele Menschen, die an einer Depression leiden, haben das Gefühl, dass sie "falsch sind", dass sie nicht zu der Welt passen, in die sie geworfen wurden, und dass sie in einer anderen Welt durchaus glücklich sein könnten. Manche fantasieren ganz konkret, sie seien adoptiert worden, bei anderen ist das Gefühl umfassender und allgemeiner und bezieht sich auf die Gesellschaft und Kultur allgemein.

Um dieses Gefühl auszudrücken, sagen manche Depressiven etwas wie:

> Ich gehöre nicht hierher.

Ich kann nicht genau sagen warum, aber irgendetwas stört mich – stilistisch oder semantisch – an diesem Satz. Vielleicht, weil "gehören" mir umgangssprachlich erscheint; vielleicht weil es zuerst die Bedeutung "besitzen" transportiert ("Das Buch gehört mir!") und erst danach die Bedeutung der Passung.

Auch andere Formulierungen desselben Gedankens, wie

> Ich bin hier falsch.

drücken für mich zuerst einmal etwas anderes aus ("Ich hab mich verlaufen."), und erst der Kontext macht dann – vielleicht – deutlich, dass gemeint ist, dass die Person nicht nur hier, in diesem Zimmer, oder jetzt, um 15:30 Uhr, "falsch" ist, sondern ganz grundsätzlich und in der ganzen Welt.

Wie kann man das besser, klarer, deutlicher formulieren, dass jemand das Gefühl hat, sich in der falschen Welt zu befinden, in einem möglichst **kurzen** und eindringlichen Satz?

Comment: Korrigiere mich, wenn ich da falsch liege: Aber "I don't belong here" ist doch das englische Äquivalent zu "Ich gehöre nicht hierher". "Belong" equals "gehören" und hat zudem auch die doppelte Bedeutung ("belong to"->jdm gehören). Insofern kein Unterschied zwischen Englisch und Deutsch.

Comment: @Em1 Das ist ganz richtig, aber warum auch immer empfinde ich die englische Formulierung anders, vielleicht weil ich die Wörter anders und in anderem Kontext gelernt habe. Mir geht es ja aber auch nicht um eine Übersetzung für den englischen Satz, sondern um eine deutsche Formulierung für eine sprachlose Vorstellung. Vielleicht lösche ich den Hinweis auf das Englische mal ...

Comment: @Em1 Wenn ich mich nicht irre, wird für den Aspekt des Besitzes ein "to" benötigt.

Comment: @Carlster Korrekt und ein Dativobjekt. Das deutsche benötigt auch ein Dativobjekt. In "Ich gehöre nicht hierhin" fehlt dieses.

Comment: @what Ich sehe kein Problem mit dem deutschen Satz. Einzige Alternative die mir in den Sinn kommt: *passen*. "Ich passe nicht hierhin".

Comment: Ich find's toll (wenn's auch nicht so außergewöhnlich sein mag), dass die zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen teilen, obwohl sie etymologisch nichts miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: Wäre eine Formulierung als Frage in Ordnung? Der erste Satz klingt als "Ich gehöre hier nicht her/hin" besser, finde ich. Eine mögliche Alternative ist "Das ist nicht meine Welt.", aber das wird viel mit ganz anderer Bedeutung verwendet.

Comment: Es gibt kein richtiges Leben im Falschen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eine gute Alternative findet sich bereits in Deiner Frage, aber nicht als Beispielsatz, sondern in der Erklärung:

> Ich passe nicht in diese Welt.

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich eine gute Möglichkeit. Vielleicht auch als: "Ich gehöre nicht in diese Welt."

Answer (score 8):

> Ich gehöre nicht hierher.

trifft es sehr gut und scheint mir vollkommen in Ordnung zu sein; "[gehören](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehoeren)" ist hier
weder umgangssprachlich noch zweideutig, da "hierher" nicht besitzen kann.

Das zweite Beispiel könnte man etwa zu

> Ich bin hier fehl am Platz.

abändern, sodass es der gewünschten Bedeutung näher kommt.

Comment: Danke dir, Carister, +1. Ich habe immer dasselbe Problem, wenn ich eine passende Formulierung für eine Vorstellung suche: keine passt! Wahrscheinlich muss ich das mal ruhen lassen und mit etwas Abstand dann nochmal die Formulierungen lesen.

Answer (score 3):

Weitere Möglichkeiten zu Carlsters Vorschlägen, an denen ich nichts auszusetzen habe:

- Das ist nicht meine Welt.
- Ich fühl mich nicht wohl in meiner Haut.
- Ich fühle mich fremd.
- Ich fühle mich heimatlos.